# String Manipulation in Bash when variable is a path

Tags: string, bash

This may be an easy question for someone more experienced than me out there. Any help would be massively appreciated.

I'm trying to manipulate a text string using the below code:

```
CONTENTS=${RESPONSEFILE%</Header></StockResponse>}
```

Where RESPONSEFILE = `/apps/live/awards/tmp/NexPhase4.tmp`

Trouble is whenever I run the above code it takes the pathname of the file and tries to manipulate that instead of opening up the file and manipulating the text within the file.

Answer (score 0):

that is exactly what bash string manipulation is supposed to do: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

what you want can be done using `sed` or other programs that allow to change files

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nikolay, I've tried using sed but it deletes the whole line of text instead of just substituting the part I want with another part. Any ideas?

sed 's@</Header></StockResponse>@<OrderComment>All medical products currently in stock</OrderComment></Header></StockResponse>@g' $RESPONSEFILE > $RESPO
NSEFILE1

Comment: your command looks ok to me; except for the fact that there's a space in the name of your output file `$RESPO NSEFILE1`. I tried it out and it works for me

Comment: Please don't link to the "Advanced" Bash-Scripting Guide. It is full of bad practices.